# Copy logical device from one computer to another

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I want to copy one logical device (look at image) with all stuff(drivers etc) to another computer. How can I do that? There is a lot apps for copying drivers, but how can I copy all stuff(with icon for logical device). And what windows' component represent this icon ?? [image: Screenshot]

Comment: No, it's no standart driver and I've lost it

Answer (score 1):

Your comments on OP and on other answers are all mentioning the (potentially real ([X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))) issue is you lost the original driver . If that was the case, you wouldn't be able to use the device at all (assuming it only needs the driver). This means it (the driver) is on your PC still.

If you open up Device Manager you should be able to see the HP device. From here, right click on it and select Properties. Go to the driver tab, click on Driver Details. Then you should see where the driver is.

You should be able to copy that driver to where you need it to be. Then you can install the HP as normal, and just update the driver to use the one you are specifying (from memory, right clicking on the printer in printers/devices will give you a driver option to specify what driver to use).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to just install driver on the other machine? Just get the up-to-date version from the vendor's website and here you go:

Here is the driver download page for your `HP LaserJet 3055`, it will install All-in-one driver:

http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome?sp4ts.oid=1140780&ac.admitted=1399543212573.876444892.199480143

Just select the proper operating system and make sure you are getting one for printer and scanner

Comment: No, it's impossible. It's no standart driver and I've lost it

Comment: What exactly is impossible? :) It's as easy as getting an installer from the website and following a simple wizard

Comment: to use standart driver, I need exactly that driver )))

Comment: I know that is strange, but is reality ;)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean by standard. What operating system were you using on the old machine and what OS are you using on new machine? Do you mean it doesn't show up in My Computer?

Comment: yea I am mean that it is not appear in my computer